# Applying a service update to Redis?

Tags: redis

I have a Redis cluster with 2 nodes in Production. Will there be any downtime or loss of data when applying a service update in this case?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by service update?

Comment: We received notification from AWS that our Redis requires the service update. When you open a Redis cluster you can see a list of service updates under the 'service update' tab. They are listed as either 'critical' or 'important'. They contain security or software updates. This one is critical and was released in March